# How to get Get-ADUser to perform better when targeting a specific server?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am obtaining an array of properties from all users in the domain.  If I do not specify a specific domain controller the query returns valid results in less than one second.  If I specify a target controller, even on my closest domain controller, the result takes 18 seconds to return.  The only difference is that I have targeted a server using `-Server $serverName`.

How do I get the same performance while specifying a server?  This is user-interface driven so waiting 18 seconds (minimum) is a long time to wait after data changes.  In the function `$serverName` pulls a stored string value, so no processing is performed.

Also, is there a way to know **which** server `Get-ADuser` pulled its information from if I don’t specify a server?

> Connected-Server:  * [Server not specified] >> Elapsed time HH:MM:SS =
>   00:00:00.9451947
>
> Connected-Server:  SERVER1 >> Elapsed time HH:MM:SS = 00:00:42.8815911
>
> Connected-Server:  SERVER2 >> Elapsed time HH:MM:SS = 00:00:39.8800249
>
> Connected-Server:  SERVER3 >> Elapsed time HH:MM:SS = 00:00:18.1686541

```
Function Get-TargetObjectList( $targetSearchBase )
{
    $propertyList  = "Enabled", "DistinguishedName", "Name", "department", "givenName","sn","displayName","CanonicalName", "Description"
    $serverName    = Get-CurrentDC  # which domain controller name did the user choose from the drop down list?

    # if $serverName is “*” then do not target a specific server

    if ($serverName -eq "*")
    {
        $tempObjects   = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -SearchBase $targetSearchBase
    } else {   
        $tempObjects   = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -Server $serverName -SearchBase $targetSearchBase
    }

    Write-Host "Get-TargetObjectList: " $serverName
    $targetObjects = $tempObjects | Select-Object -Property $propertyList | Sort-Object -Property Name
    return $targetObjects
}
```

Comment: So I can't help with the performance issue that you are seeing except to ask when you run it without specifying a server, is that the first AD related command that you have run during the session or were other commands run previously?  if it's not the first AD command in your session it is possible that you have an existing connection and that is what is being used, whereas if you provide -server a new connection is being established.  beyond that the environment variable `$env:LogonServer` should at least be able to tell you which DC you are defaulting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Mike Garuccio and Andy Simmons answers I decided to strip away everything except the below and look at a single server, which is my closest server.
I encountered a strange combination of events which is reproducible.

```
$stopwatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$stopwatch.Start()

$targetSearchBase = "OU=User Accounts,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=com"
$propertyList  = "Enabled", "DistinguishedName", "Name", "department", "givenName","displayName","CanonicalName", "Description"
#$propertyList  = "Enabled", "DistinguishedName", "Name", "department", "givenName","sn","displayName","CanonicalName", "Description"
$serverName = "TARGET_SERVER_NAME"

$tempObjects = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -Server $serverName -SearchBase $targetSearchBase

#server not specified
#$tempObjects = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -SearchBase $targetSearchBase
$targetObjects = $tempObjects | Select-Object -Property $propertyList | Sort-Object -Property Name

$stopwatch.Stop()
$elapsedTime = $stopwatch.Elapsed
$elapsed = "Elapsed time HH:MM:SS = $($elapsedTime)"
Write-Host "Server: " $serverName
Write-Host "server data retrieved: " $elapsed
```

If I do not specify a server, the list is retrieved in less than 1 second

```
 $tempObjects = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -SearchBase $targetSearchBase
```

If I do specify my closest server, the list is retrieved in 18 seconds

```
 $tempObjects = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -Server $serverName -SearchBase $targetSearchBase
```

After looking through all of the object properties I noticed that the command retrieved the property “Surname” and “sn”, even though I had only chosen “sn”.

```
 $tempObjects | Get-Member
```

This is because Get-ADUser pulls other properties by default, where “Surname” is one of them (see the link below).  Once I removed my request for the “sn” property, even with specifying the server, the data was obtained in 3 seconds.  I then tested the server that is furthest away and that took only 6 seconds after removing “sn” from the retrieved properties, verses 42 seconds with it.

```
 Select-Object -Property $propertyList
```

There is one more oddity that I found. When the Select-Object statement is included, the resolution time goes up **dramatically** but **only** when "sn" is included in the property list.

I now know how to more precisely target the problem and can resolve it but at this time I don't have a concrete answer as to why the anomaly exists.  Hopefully, this question will help someone else.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at `Trace-Command`? You can use `Get-TraceSource` to get some ideas about how you could cut down on some of the noise, but as a starting point, try something like this:

```
Trace-Command -Name "*" -Expression { Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $propertyList -Server $serverName -SearchBase $targetSearchBase }
```

You'll likely get an idea where it's hanging up.

Comment: I started with using the Trace-Command as you suggested.  Although it didn't directly lead me to my conclusion, it did get me started at focusing on strictly the essentials.