# longer execution time after Get-ADUser when a server is specified

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that queries AD and processes the result:

```
$users=Get-ADUser -filter {...} -Properties ...
try { 
   foreach($user in $users) {
     $obj=new-object PSObject @property {...}
     [void]($arraylist.add($obj))
   }
} 
catch {...}
```

the `Get-ADUser` takes about 1.5sec and returns 1000+ rows, and the whole `try` block takes about 0.5sec.

the `@Properties {...}` part only processes `$user` fields and has no further interaction with the AD or any other resource. the `try` block runs without error.

if now I change the first line to

```
$users=Get-ADUser -filter {...} -Properties ... -Server <someDC>
```

just adding a `-Server` parameter, the `Get-ADUser`command takes about 3sec and the `try` block **20+sec**

I tried many times to be sure that the remote connection is well established without any improvement. I tried with each of the available DCs and got the very same execution time each time. If I remove the `-Server` parameter, I get the original execution time back.

the problem has similarities with the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307397/how-to-get-get-aduser-to-perform-better-when-targeting-a-specific-server) but the my problem is with the code executed **after** the `Get-ADUser`, not with the `Get-ADUser` by itself.

what is very disturbing is that it's the code **after** which get slower.

do you have any clue?

```
DC: Win2008R2
Client: Win7, Powershell5.1, AD Management Tools locally installed.
```

Comment: as i recall, there is supposed to be a cmdlet that will give you the "nearest" DC. is that how you chose the DC you are connecting to? ///// you likely otta post the entire code in question ... something in your parameters seems to be adding to the delay ... but you have not shown what that code _is_. [*grin*]

Comment: Try with `$dc = (Get-ADDomaincontroller -DomainName $Domain -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName` and use $dc for the `-Server` parameter. You need Server 2012 or 2016 for this I believe. If you don't have that you can use `$dc = Get-ADDomain -Current LoggedOnUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PDCEmulator`